# store text from uitextfield to a dictionary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

Is there a way to get the text from a uitextfield and save that into a dictionary at a certain key?  I've tried numerous combinations but they either fail or do not enter the text.  Here is what I have now that is not working:

```
NSString *string = self.userName.text;
string = [registration objectForKey:@"Username"];
```

but it doesnt enter the information at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've instantiated an instance of `NSMutableDictionary` for `registration`:

```
[registration setObject:string forKey:@"Username"];
```

will put a value into the dictionary for a given key, and

```
string = [registration objectForKey:@"Username"];
```

will retrieve it.

Comment: It crashes and says 'object cannot be nil (key: Username)'

Comment: Then you need to find out why `string` is nil. I see you're retrieving it from a text field. Is your text field connected to your controller; i.e., is `userName` (which I assume represents your text field) non-nil?

Comment: yes I have userName connected to my controller.  Not sure what you mean by non-nil.  I am entering information into it every time I test it if thats what you mean.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that, if you don't have a valid reference to your text field (that is, it's nil), then any attempt to retrieve an instance of NSString from that reference is also going to be nil. What you've said suggests that `string` is nil.

Comment: How would I check to see if I have a valid reference?

Comment: Examine the value of `userName`, which I assume is a reference to your text field. If it's nil, it's not valid.